# How do I hide a button until all elements are clicked in HTML?

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to hide a button until all required elements on the page have been clicked. I found how to hide an element until one item is clicked but not sure how to set this to hide the button until **all** items are clicked.

The elements I want the users to click on are accordion panels with the ID's as "collaspeone", "collaspetwo" and so on. I want the user to click on each panel (which causes them to expand) then once they have clicked on each panel, show a button on the bottom of the page which allows them to continue to the next page.

Here is the element I want to show only when every panel has been clicked on.

```
<button id="Continue" class="btn btn-primary"><a href="AddSupplier-SubmitReq.aspx" style="color:white">Continue to Set-Up<i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></button>
```

Here is my full HTML code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<%@ Register tagprefix="SharePoint" namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
<head>
<meta name="WebPartPageExpansion" content="full" />
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <link rel="canonical" href="http://html5-templates.com/" />
 <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-touch-icon.png"/>
 <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon-32x32.png"/>
 <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon-16x16.png"/>
 <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json"/>
 <link rel="mask-icon" href="/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5"/>
 <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff"/>
    <title>MySLM Portal</title>
 <meta name="description" content="A minimalist Bootstrap theme by StartBootstrap. Contains everything you need to get started building your website. All you have to do is change the text and images.">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="css/modern-business.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="css/footer.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#myModal").modal('show');
    });
</script>
<!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Script to Activate the Carousel -->
    <script>
    $('.carousel').carousel({
        interval: 5000 //changes the speed
    })
    
    </script>
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.dropdown-submenu a.submenu').on("click", function(e){
     $(this).next('ul').toggle();
     e.stopPropagation();
     e.preventDefault();
    });
 });
 </script>
 
</head>

<body>

    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <img src="https://cargillonline.sharepoint.com/sites/ProcureToPay/SitePages/MySLM/Assets/CargillLogo.png"/>
                <a href="Home.aspx"><img src="https://cargillonline.sharepoint.com/sites/ProcureToPay/SitePages/MySLM/Assets/SLMPortal.png"/></a>
                </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li>
                        <a href="Scope.aspx">Scope</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="AddSupplier-FirstSteps.aspx">General Questions</a>
                    </li>
                      <li>
                        <a href="FAQs.aspx">FAQ's</a>
                    </li>
       <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Processes<b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li>
                                <a href="../Create.aspx" target="_blank">Create a New Supplier</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="../Update.aspx" target="_blank">Update an Existing Supplier</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="../Reactivate.aspx" target="_blank">Reactivate a Supplier</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="../Deactivate.aspx" target="_blank">Deactivate a Supplier</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="Contact-Us.aspx">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Resources<b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li>
                                <a href="../ERS.aspx" target="_blank">ERS Agreement Library</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="../Corp Record List.aspx" target="_blank">Corp Record List</a>
                            </li>
       <li>
                                <a href="../Sanctioned Supplier List.aspx" target="_blank">Sanctioned Supplier List</a>
                            </li>
       <li>
                                <a href="../Supplier Deactivation Listing.aspx" target="_blank">Supplier Deactivation Listing</a>
                            </li>

                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="https://team.cargill.com/sites/NAP/HELP/SitePages/RemedyForce.aspx" target="_blank">RemedyForce Training</a>
                            </li>
                            <li> 
                                <a href="http://strategicsourcing.cargill.com/PROCUREMENT/procurementwebsite.nsf/" target="_blank">Select Supplier Search</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="https://www.yammer.com/cargill.com/#/threads/inGroup?type=in_group&feedId=620515" target="_blank">Yammer: Source to Pay NA</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="JobAids.aspx">Job Aids</a>
                            </li>
       <li>
                                <a href="SelfHelp.aspx">Knowledge/Self Help Articles</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                <a tabindex="-1" href="#" class="submenu">Policies<b class="caret"></b></a>
           <ul class="dropdown-menu">
           <li><a tabindex="-1" href="https://sites.cargill.com/sites/PolicyCenter/Pages/Spending%20Policies/Sourcing-and-Purchasing-Policy.aspx" target="_blank">Sourcing and Purchasing Policy</a></li>
           <li class="divider"></li>     
           <li><a tabindex="-1" href="https://sites.cargill.com/sites/PolicyCenter/Pages/Business%20Conduct%20Pages/Anti-bribery-Policy.aspx" target="_blank">Anti-bribery Policy</a></li>
           <li><a tabindex="-1" href="https://sites.cargill.com/sites/PolicyCenter/Pages/Financial%20and%20Market%20Risks/Bank-Account--Payment-Control-Policy.aspx" target="_blank">Bank Account &amp; Payment Control Policy</a></li>
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="https://sites.cargill.com/sites/PolicyCenter/Pages/Business%20Conduct%20Pages/Competition-Policy.aspx" target="_blank">Competition Policy</a></li>
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="https://sites.cargill.com/sites/PolicyCenter/Pages/Business%20Conduct%20Pages/Conflicts-of-Interest-Policy.aspx" target="_blank">Conflicts of Interest Policy</a></li>
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="https://sites.cargill.com/sites/PolicyCenter/Pages/Financial%20and%20Market%20Risks/Country-Risk-Policy.aspx" target="_blank">Country Risk Policy</a></li>
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="https://sites.cargill.com/sites/PolicyCenter/Pages/Business%20Conduct%20Pages/Insider-Trading-Policy.aspx" target="_blank">Insider Trading Policy</a></li>
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="https://sites.cargill.com/sites/PolicyCenter/Pages/Business%20Conduct%20Pages/Legal-Services-Policy.aspx" target="_blank">Legal Services Policy</a></li>
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="https://sites.cargill.com/sites/Ethics_Compliance/suppliercode/Pages/default.aspx" target="_blank">Supplier Code of Conduct</a></li>
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="https://sites.cargill.com/sites/PolicyCenter/Pages/Business%20Conduct%20Pages/Trade-Sanctions-Policy.aspx" target="_blank">Trade Sanctions Policy</a></li>
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="https://sites.cargill.com/sites/PolicyCenter/_layouts/15/WopiFrame.aspx?sourcedoc=/sites/PolicyCenter/SiteCollectionDocuments/Spending/Sourcing.Purchasing/United%20States%20and%20Canada%20Purchasing%20Cards%20Procedure.docx&action=default" target="_blank">United states &amp; Canada Purchasing Cards Procedure</a></li>
        </ul>
                            </li>  
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Links<b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li> 
                                <a href="http://cargill.sourcing.ariba.com" target="_blank">Ariba</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="https://team.cargill.com/sites/P2PNA/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/Lists/Business_Stakeholder_Library/Tiles.aspx" target="_blank">P2P Business Stakeholder Library</a>                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="https://cargill15--bmcservicedesk.na74.visual.force.com/apex/StdSelfServiceHome?sfdc.tabName=01ro0000000HBPc&tsid=02uo00000002kY1" target="_blank">RemedyForce</a>
                            </li>                         
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="https://cargillonline.sharepoint.com/search/Pages/results.aspx?k=" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>
 
 <!-- Modale -->
 <div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
     <div class="modal-dialog">
         <div class="modal-content">
             <div class="modal-header">
                 <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                 <h4 class="modal-title">Wait! Make Your Job Easier!</h4>
             </div>
             <div class="modal-body">
              <p><b>Source through CSSP!</b></p>
                 <p>By sourcing through CSSP you can avoid having to navigate the entire complex supplier setup process and focus on your job while CSSP works for you in the background sourcing you a supplier and having them set-up in the appropriate ERP system for your use!</p>
                 <button class="btn btn-primary"><a href="Source.aspx" style="color:white">Lets go!  <i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></button>
                 <p>&nbsp;</p>
                 <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">No, I do not want to make my job easier</button>
         </div>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
 <!-- /.modale -->
 
    <!-- Page Content -->
  
    <div class="container">
 <!-- Page Heading/Breadcrumbs -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h1 class="page-header">Set-up a New Supplier
                    <small>First Steps</small>
                </h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    <!-- /.row -->
    <!-- Content Row -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script>
 $('div.panel-group#accordion .panel').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('clicked');
    var count = $(this).parent().find('.panel').length, ctr = 0;
    $(this).parent().find('.panel').each(function() {
     if($(this).hasClass('clicked')) { ctr++; }
    });
    if(ctr === count) { 
      $('button#Continue').removeClass('hidden disabled'); 
    }
 })
 </script>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-12">
    <p style="font-size:14pt">The following steps should be completed by the requester prior to submitting a request to set-up a new supplier. Failure to perform these steps may result in rejection of, or delays on your request.</p>
   </div>
  </div>
    <!-- Content Row -->
        <!-- Content Row -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
      <!-- panel -->
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
              <table>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      <span class="fa-stack fa-2x">
                        <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x text-primary"></i>
                        <i class="fa-stack-1x fa-inverse">1</i>
                      </span>
                    </td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td style="font-size:16pt">Panel Title</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </a>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body">
            <p>Panel Body</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- /.panel -->
      <!-- panel -->
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapsetwo">
              <table>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      <span class="fa-stack fa-2x">
                        <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x text-primary"></i>
                        <i class="fa-stack-1x fa-inverse">2</i>
                      </span>
                    </td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td style="font-size:16pt">Panel Title</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </a>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapsetwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body">
            <p>Panel Body</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- /.panel -->
      <!-- panel -->
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapsethree">
              <table>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      <span class="fa-stack fa-2x">
                        <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x text-primary"></i>
                        <i class="fa-stack-1x fa-inverse">3</i>
                      </span>
                    </td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td style="font-size:16pt">Panel Title</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </a>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapsethree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body">
            <p>Panel Body</p>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- /.panel -->
      <!-- panel -->
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapsefour">
              <table>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      <span class="fa-stack fa-2x">
                        <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x text-primary"></i>
                        <i class="fa-stack-1x fa-inverse">4</i>
                      </span>
                    </td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td style="font-size:16pt">Panel Title</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </a>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapsefour" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body">
            <p>Panel Body</p>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- /.panel -->
      <!-- panel -->
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapsefive">
              <table>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      <span class="fa-stack fa-2x">
                        <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x text-primary"></i>
                        <i class="fa-stack-1x fa-inverse">5</i>
                      </span>
                    </td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td style="font-size:16pt">Panel Title</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </a>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapsefive" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body">
            <p>Panel Body</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- /.panel -->

    </div>
    <!-- /.panel-group -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
</div>             
        <!--Continue button -->

        <button id="Continue" class="btn btn-primary hidden disabled"><a href="AddSupplier-SubmitReq.aspx" style="color:white">Continue to Set-Up<i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></button>
  
  <!--/.Continue button -->

        
        <!--Check out FAQ's -->
        <hr>
        <div class="well">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <p>Questions? Check out our FAQ's</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" href="Faqs.aspx">Go to FAQ's!</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--/.Check out FAQ's -->
     </div>
     <!-- /.row -->

    <!-- Footer -->
    <div style="padding-top:30px">
    
    <div class="footer-position hidden-print ms-dialogHidden" style="padding-top: 0px;">
    <div class="ava footer">
        <div class="inner">
            <div class="top">
                <div class="thrive left">
                    <div class="inner"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="thrive right">
                    <div class="inner"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="bottom container-fluid clearfix">
                <div class="row clearfix" data-bind="foreach: footerData">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-2 pull-right text-right">
                        <div class="link">
                            <a data-bind="text: $data.Title, attr: { href: $data.Url}" href="https://sites.cargill.com/sites/Ethics_Compliance/CodeConduct/Pages/default.aspx">Code of Conduct</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-2 pull-right text-right">
                        <div class="link">
                            <a data-bind="text: $data.Title, attr: { href: $data.Url}" href="https://sites.cargill.com/sites/Ethics_Compliance/suppliercode/Pages/default.aspx">Supplier Code of Conduct</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-2 pull-right text-right">
                        <div class="link">
                            <a data-bind="text: $data.Title, attr: { href: $data.Url}" href="https://sites.cargill.com/sites/PolicyCenter/Pages/default.aspx">Policy Center</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="copyright pull-right">© <span data-bind="text: year">2017</span> Cargill, Incorporated. All Rights Reserved</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
   <!-- /.Footer -->
 

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Create an accumulator and increment its value on each click and when it reaches the count of collpase-able panel value, show your button.

Comment: Or add a class to each selector (id) on click. If all selectors have the class, show the button.

Comment: please, paste your JS that you used to try...

Comment: I am unsure how to write this code. Could you give an example?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way I can think of is to keep track of the clicked elements. 
If the array you're keeping track of is the same length as the number of elements to click, display the nutton.

```js
$(function(){

  // an array to keep track of the clicked elements
  var clicked = [];
  
  $('.panel').click(function(e){
 
    // only add them if they are not already clicked before
    if(!clicked.includes(event.target.id)){
     clicked.push(event.target.id);
      
      // once the clicked elements array is the same length as all the  
    // elements that need to be clicked, display the button
    if(clicked.length === $('.panel').length){
     $('#theButton').show();
    };
    }
    
    
  });
  
  
});
```

```css
.panel{
  float: left;
  width: 30px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.hidden{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="p1" class="panel">1</div>
<div id="p2" class="panel">2</div>
<div id="p3" class="panel">3</div>
<div id="p4" class="panel">4</div>
<button id="theButton" class="hidden">move on</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `href`(It is different for each panel) on click of a panel inside an accumulator, when its length reaches `5` display your button.

```js
var panelsClicked = [];
$('.panel').on('click', function() {
  var href = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
  if(!panelsClicked.includes(href)){
    panelsClicked.push(href);
    if(panelsClicked.length === 5) {
      $('#Continue').show();
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Content Row -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
            <!-- panel -->
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
                                <table>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <span class="fa-stack fa-2x">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x text-primary"></i>
                                                    <i class="fa-stack-1x fa-inverse">1</i>
                                                </span>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td style="font-size:16pt">Panel Title</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <p>Panel Body</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.panel -->
                <!-- panel -->
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapsetwo">
                                <table>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <span class="fa-stack fa-2x">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x text-primary"></i>
                                                    <i class="fa-stack-1x fa-inverse">2</i>
                                                </span>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td style="font-size:16pt">Panel Title</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapsetwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <p>Panel Body</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.panel -->
                <!-- panel -->
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapsethree">
                                <table>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <span class="fa-stack fa-2x">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x text-primary"></i>
                                                    <i class="fa-stack-1x fa-inverse">3</i>
                                                </span>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td style="font-size:16pt">Panel Title</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapsethree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <p>Panel Body</p>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.panel -->
                <!-- panel -->
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapsefour">
                                <table>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <span class="fa-stack fa-2x">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x text-primary"></i>
                                                    <i class="fa-stack-1x fa-inverse">4</i>
                                                </span>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td style="font-size:16pt">Panel Title</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapsefour" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <p>Panel Body</p>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.panel -->
                <!-- panel -->
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapsefive">
                                <table>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <span class="fa-stack fa-2x">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x text-primary"></i>
                                                    <i class="fa-stack-1x fa-inverse">5</i>
                                                </span>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td style="font-size:16pt">Panel Title</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapsefive" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <p>Panel Body</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button style="display:none;" id="Continue" class="btn btn-primary"><a href="AddSupplier-SubmitReq.aspx" style=" color:white">Continue to Set-Up<i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></button>
                <!-- /.panel -->

            </div>
            <!-- /.panel-group -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
    </div>
```

Comment: Pretty much the same answer as mine, but why use href? This will change the URL in the browser. That seems to me like unwanted side effects, since the # in the browser might want to be used for other things.

In my answer I track ID's, which might be more suitable in this case.

Comment: Still even the changed `href` values will be unique for each panel. You have added id to each panel which require modification of HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Another variation would be to add a class "**clicked**" and display the button if the number of panels with class **clicked** is equal to total number of panels within the accordion.

```js
$('div.panel-group#accordion .panel').click(function() {
  $(this).addClass('clicked');
  var count = $(this).parent().find('.panel').length, ctr = 0;
  $(this).parent().find('.panel').each(function() {
   if($(this).hasClass('clicked')) { ctr++; }
  });
  if(ctr === count) { 
    $('button#Continue').removeClass('hidden disabled'); 
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- Content Row -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
            <!-- panel -->
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
                                <table>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <span class="fa-stack fa-2x">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x text-primary"></i>
                                                    <i class="fa-stack-1x fa-inverse">1</i>
                                                </span>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td style="font-size:16pt">Panel Title</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <p>Panel Body</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.panel -->
                <!-- panel -->
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapsetwo">
                                <table>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <span class="fa-stack fa-2x">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x text-primary"></i>
                                                    <i class="fa-stack-1x fa-inverse">2</i>
                                                </span>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td style="font-size:16pt">Panel Title</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapsetwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <p>Panel Body</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.panel -->
                <!-- panel -->
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapsethree">
                                <table>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <span class="fa-stack fa-2x">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x text-primary"></i>
                                                    <i class="fa-stack-1x fa-inverse">3</i>
                                                </span>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td style="font-size:16pt">Panel Title</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapsethree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <p>Panel Body</p>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.panel -->
                <!-- panel -->
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapsefour">
                                <table>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <span class="fa-stack fa-2x">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x text-primary"></i>
                                                    <i class="fa-stack-1x fa-inverse">4</i>
                                                </span>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td style="font-size:16pt">Panel Title</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapsefour" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <p>Panel Body</p>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.panel -->
                <!-- panel -->
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapsefive">
                                <table>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <span class="fa-stack fa-2x">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x text-primary"></i>
                                                    <i class="fa-stack-1x fa-inverse">5</i>
                                                </span>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td style="font-size:16pt">Panel Title</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapsefive" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <p>Panel Body</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.panel -->

            </div>
            <!-- /.panel-group -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
    </div>
    
    <button id="Continue" class="btn btn-primary hidden disabled"><a href="AddSupplier-SubmitReq.aspx" style="color:white">Continue to Set-Up<i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></button>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: nice solution. You can simplify the code by using `$(this).parent().find('.clicked').length` instead of using the `each` loop. 
So it would be:


`$(this).parent().find('.clicked').length === $(this).parent().find('.panel').length`.

Adding the clicked class makes it possible to indicate to the user which ones he has already read and which ones he still needs to red.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, right! That's a variation as well. I don't know why but a loop came to my mind while typing a solution and I just posted it. Btw I'll edit it. Thanks again.

Comment: Thank you. I tried it by entering the script into the header section and body to no avail. (I also made edits to the button). I edited my original post with my full html code